# Importing Excel to internal table with same layout

Tags: abap, import-from-excel

I know of function module ALSM_EXCEL_TO_INTERNAL_TABLE. This FM creates an internal table with three columns (row, column, value). But I want to create an internal table which has the same layout as my Excel sheet. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use class cl_mass_spreadsheet_service if you are uploading the excel in foreground. See my example code below:

```
DATA:
    lv_file      TYPE if_mass_spreadsheet_types=>file_name,
    lt_result    TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zsd_salesorder_create. "your result table

lv_file = 'C:\some_file.xlsx'.

cl_mass_spreadsheet_service=>fill_table(
    EXPORTING
        iv_file                     = lv_file   "full path+name of file. See method navigate_to_file below
        iv_from_file                = abap_true "use to upload from excel/CSV
        iv_from_clipboard           = abap_false "use to copy directly from clipbiard
        iv_tabname                  = 'Order_Create' "can be whatever
    CHANGING
        ct_table                    = lt_result "if ct_table have the same column names as the excel file, the order of the columns does not matter
).
```

Comment: This class requires DDIC structure, so this is not fully dynamic structure-solution, but anyway functional! Better that I saw ever, cheers!

Comment: It's also worth to mention, this class appeared only since 7.40, it doesn't exists in 7.31 and older systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you upload the data with FM ALSM_EXCEL_TO_INTERNAL_TABLE, you can LOOP through the internal table this FM is uses (the one with row, column, value as you mentioned) and fill your own internal table (which looks like the Excel sheet) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 
cl_mass_spreadsheet_service=>import_from_file 
as well but without ddic structure.

Unfortunately, these methods will actually open and show EXCEL...